# django: See the result of a python script in my webpage

Tags: python, ajax, django, popen

I am developing a website using Django. I want to see the result of a python script on my webpage. And after some searching, I realized subprocess popen can help me. I am very new to Django so I searched for a complete code. I find these lines:

```
output = None
    cmd = 'python ' + session["file_name"]
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    output = p.stdout.read()

return jsonify(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

from PythonBuddy opensource code. But it uses flask and I don't know what will be the replacement for it in Django.

Here is my view.py:(It doesn't work)

```
output = None
def home(request):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python","adoptions/executer.py"], close_fds=True)
    std_out, std_error = p.communicate()
    return jsonify(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

The python code in executer.py is a game, not something like a string to print, so many codes I found was useless.

Can it be easier if I use ajax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to get just script output use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/subprocess.check_output) function.

When you want to return json from django view, the JsonResponse is best match for you.

```
import subprocess
from django.http import JsonResponse

def home(request):
    output = subprocess.check_output(["python","adoptions/executer.py"])
    return JsonResponse(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't have any error anymore, but it opens up a consul and shows the result there, I want to see the result on my webpage. :(